# ng-messages not showing in directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to re-use code as much as I can so I'm wrapping `ng-messages` in a directive. However, the messages are not shown..

```
<form name="elementForm" novalidate>
<md-input-container>
  <label>Category</label>
  <input ng-required="true" ng-model="item.category" name="category" type="text">
<administration-input-validation control="category" formname="elementForm"></administration-input-validation>
</md-input-container>
</form>
```

**Directive:**

```
    angular.module('app.analytics')
  .directive('administrationInputValidation', function () {
    return {
      template:
      '<div ng-messages>' +
        '<div ng-message="required">This is required</div>' +
      '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      require: '^form',
      scope: {
        control: '=',
        formname: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var formStr = attrs.formname + "." + attrs.control;
        element.attr("ng-messages", formStr + "." + "$error");
      }
    };
  });
```

I also tried hardcoding but it's still not showing

`<div ng-messages="elementForm.category.$error">`

**UPDATE**

Binding works now, but it's not showing the messages

Comment: what about add in the scope binds : `error:'='` and in your html : `error=elementForm.category.$error` ?

Comment: @Walfrat The thing is, it needs to be down dynamically. I've updated the OP with a working binding, but it's not showing anything

Comment: No your code won't work like this, only doing `<administration-input-validation error="elementForm.category.$error" ...>` and add the binding  in the scope attribute of directive and change your template's by `<div ng-messages = "error">...</div>` will work. And if you have some kind of automation like looping on field  you can have  `<administration-input-validation error="elementForm[currentField].$error" ...>`